# jRuby / Rails how to compare one Hash value to another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, hash, jruby

What I have is 2 hash's one gets dumped from a backend that deals nothing specifically with rails. The other is a manually built hard-coded hash. Kind of like a index of known possibilities.

What I want to do is compare what the backend spits out vs what I have in my hash thats like an index so when I render my view I can have the display look a bit more appealing.

Now I could do something like this with php and an array

```
array("monkey" => "Monkey", "server" => "server")
and then do a str_replace("monkey", $var, array)
```

ok thats a poor example but its been a while since I played with php and I am a bit rusty off the top of my head. But thats the notion

the end result is when I find "monkey" in one I want to replace it with "Monkey" for the view's sake.

**edit/revision/addition**

Ok realized Im not working with a hash, im actually working with an array or a JSON object..

```
pretty_service = {"namenode" => "Name Nodes","secondarynamenode" => " Secondary Name Nodes", "datanode" => "Data Nodes", "web" => "Web", "tasktracker" => "Task Trackers", "jobtracker" => "Job Trackers", "oozie" => "Oozie", "single-namenode" => "Single NameNode", "single-databse" => "Single Database" }
```

What I want to is if my strings I am checking contain any one of the keys I want to replace it with the value. Not sure how exactly to do that with rails styling coding. There is some decent concepts below already but I've tried them and they don't seem to work for me. Knowing this now, is there a differnt approach to working this up?

Comment: You haven't provided sample input or sample output. This makes it very difficult to answer with sufficient detail.

Comment: Why iterate through your entire hash? Why not just add a `.capitalize` in your view helper?

Comment: How do you create the hash? Perhaps at that time you can make it correct, rather than having to process it a second time.

Comment: Can't capitalize.. as some of the names I want to catch are like Monkey-X354 and I just want monkey

Comment: Is there a consistent transformation? e.g. something a regex could do?

Comment: For a StackOverview expert, your question is quite confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

String.gsub can do that.

```
table = {"monkey"=>"Monkey", "teh"=>"the"}
str = "Don't feed teh monkey"
p str.gsub(Regexp.union(table.keys), table)
#=> "Don't feed the Monkey"
```

Comment: This idea, I like it, but I need to do it in a way where if theres a match do it, if there isn't leave it be. In a sense if-else style. Is there a way? or will it leave the string intact if theres no match?

Comment: Try it! Just change `str = "Don't feed teh monkey"` to `str = "no matches here"` and see what happens.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of using the hash functions. You can adapt this to your needs:

```
if my_hash.keys.include?("monkey")
   what_i_will_render.gsub!("monkey",my_hash["monkey"])
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
find = {:a => 'a', :b => 'b', :c => 'c'}
replace = {:a => 'A', :b => 'B'}
replace.merge(find) # {:a => 'A', :b => 'B', :c => 'c'}
```

Comment: hmm yes, maybe that is what the OP wants.